# Enable two wireless network interfaces in linux

Tags: kali-linux, wireless-adapter

I am currently using Kali Linux and I need to use two network interfaces ie. WLAN0 and WLAN1. I have connected usb wireless adapter in addition to my laptop's wifi adapter but only one works (internal adapter). I have successfully installed the driver but still only wlan0 is shown. I have searched the internet but could only find solutions for the driver problem. I rather need help to edit interface or something so that I can use both adapters at a time in wlan0 and wlan1.
Note: I tried another usb adapter(RaLink) and It works totally fine but in case of realtek semiconductor adapter I am having this problem. And also in windows it is working perfectly fine as well. I can see wifi and wifi2.

Comment: Do your adapters connect to different subnets and to different `SSID`s? What IP addresses do you give them (or are they getting -if you're using DHCP)?

Comment: my usb adapter is not detected at all. when i type ifconfig i can only see wlan0 which i believe is the internal adapter. I have installed the driver but it does not show up

Comment: how did you install it? Is it loaded? Do you see it when you type `lsmod`?

Comment: i had the driver cd with me and which had the linux folder in it but that didn't install so i searched for that driver in the internet and downloaded it and installed.
The device id is 0bda:f179 whose driver should be rtl8188ftv but i couldnot find its linux version and even the driver cd had rtl8192cu.
maybe its a driver problem?
When I type lsmod i get a long list. Which part are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure, go through the list and see if you can spot a sriver that aligns with your rtl device. Otherwise find the drive file (loadabla kernel module) and load it using `modprobe`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it working no I had installed the wrong driver the whole time. The correct driver was rtl8188fu

Comment: I've added the reply as an answer below, please accept & upvote for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lsmod` you can see & figure out which kernel drivers are currently loaded. It will need to align with the device you have plugged in. If it does not, you may not have a matching driver installed & loaded.